# Can not set AWS SSO with Cloudflare SAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, cloudflare

i'm trying to set AWS SSO (now AWS Identity Center) to login to Cloudflare. When i login to aws portal and then click to Cloudflare app i get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXRja.jpg

These are the settings of aws and Cloudflare

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlQ0q.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW2jG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYn79.jpg

i tried to change mapping value with no success

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have same issue.  I engaged Cloudflare support and they indicated that at this time, Cloudflare doesn't support IDP login only SDP login.

In other words, the login must initiate from https://dash.cloudflare.com/login.
When the user enters their email address, the password field will be greyed out and the button will change to "Login with SSO".
When they click on the button, it will route them to your SSO, validate the user and let them in.

This works for us, again as long as we initiate the login from the Cloudflare side.
I have asked Cloudflare to please fix this, but no response yet.